# Toggle text from Spanish to English while keeping special characters

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a website and put on a button which toggles the text from an inner html pair of tags

Button:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="langbutton">Change to English</button>
```

Function:

```
  var x = document.getElementById("langbutton");
    if (x.innerHTML === "Change to English") {
    x.innerHTML = "Cambiar a Espa単ol";
    } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Change to English";
    }

var x = document.getElementById("inicio");
  if (x.innerHTML === "INICIO") {
    x.innerHTML = "HOME";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "INICIO";
  }
```

The first one is for the button to toggle from English to spanish, the second is for the "Home" link in the navBar. This works perfectly but whenever there is a Spanish character such as "¿, ó...", it shows a questionmark inside a rhomboid. I tried using HTML entity codes from
http://kourbatov.com/faq/accentedcharacters.htm
But it will not work.
So far I've deleted all of these special characters off of the website but that means that many words are misspelled.

Using the same variable, in this case "x" for each, or changing the variable for anything else doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You might need to add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside `<head>` tag  in your HTML document

Comment: Not only the meta, the file (.js or .html, where this special character is) should be also saved with UTF-8.

Comment: I had it set to UTF-8 on the html and the .js was also saved in this manner. No changes.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I hadn't done that because after trying out different things, I think I did that and then it worked, I thought I had already done it before.

Comment: If you could make this comment an answer to mark it please.